# WPF adding references broken after moving project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution consisting of a WPF app. After some juggling of dir paths I cannot add references to my projects anymore. Whenever I do "add reference" in visual studio 2013 I get an error:

> Cannot locate resource 'shared/standardresources.xaml'

I can build the solution just fine in VS.

Due to company policy the structure of my solution is like this (note the **src** dir):

```
x.sln
src/wpfApp/wpfApp.csproj
```

However, it turns out I get the same problem even if I just create new project in the default place in a new solution. I can reproduce the problem as described above like this:

1. Create a blank solution
2. In Windows Explorer create a src directory in the solution
3. In VS, Add a new WPF Application to the solution. Store it underneath the src dir created previously.
4. Now try adding references to the WPF Application by right clicking it in Solution explorer. The error message appears.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *After some juggling of dir paths*... ding ding ding ding ding ding. (That's the sound of alarm bells ringing).

Comment: Ha ha, it sounds worse than it is. I just moved the projects into the src subdir, and then added the projects to the solution again. VS was closed while I was doing the moving.

Comment: Where is the `shared` folder in your structure?

Comment: It does not exist, and I did not create and delete it either. It is very strange.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Your steps 1 to 4 work well for me.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I got everything back to normal by rebooting the PC .. it works now.

Answer (score 1):

To the noobs like myself out here you can try to move the projects into the new src folder and add the projects back into the solution. Also, verify you are using the absolute correct version of the dlls. Wrong versions can occur when setting up a new development machine. (Making certain the most current and correct libraries are on the new machine is one more reason to "image" a known good dev harddrive as a baseline.) Edit the project file and look at the references version="value" and compare to the installed components.